# How to notify client's child classes property changes from my parent class?

Tags: c#, propertychanged

I am writing a library and my clients using my library.

My clients creates own classes derived from my base class.

Can i detect my client's class property is changed?

I don't want my clients to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

I am also using reflection for other purposes. Why reflection can't detect properties change status?

My library code:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public void ChildPropertyChanged(propinfo...)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Client's code:

```
public class MyClass : BaseClass
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Supper classes are not supposed to be aware of sub classes.

Comment: Clients will not override my methods. Yes clients can put much but usually this classes are not complex only properties and some methods maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Your clients must collaborate, meaning they will have to write code to help you catch the change of properties, as in INotifyPropertyChanged clients (implementers) must raise an event (RaisePropertyChanged);

If you think about it, if what you are asking was possible, than INotifyPropertyChanged was not necessary..

One possible solution for you is to define an event in the base class, and guide your clients to raise it in their properties getters, or even better - calling a base class handler method.

Comment: I am curious about is there a way to implement without INotifyPropertyChanged?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the [template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) pattern.

Base class.

```
public class BaseClass
{
    protected string name;

    private void NameChanged()
    {
         ...
    }

    public void SetName(string value)
    {
        this.name = value;
        this.NameChanged();
    }
}
```

Derived class:

```
public class MyClass : BaseClass
{
    public string Name 
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.name; 
        }

        set 
        {
            this.SetName(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Although doing it this way eliminates the need for the property in the derived class - it can be changed using the base class method `SetName`.

Comment: How can i know what will implement in derived class? This is impossible.

Comment: They will be adding their own properties and you have no control over it?  If so then not sure if it's possible without using `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  How about writing a `PropertyChanged` event and asking them to raise it when necessary with a before and after value or something for the `EventArgs`.